# How to build C extensions via poetry?

Tags: python, python-c-api, python-poetry

To build a python project managed with `poetry` I need to build C extensions first (an equivalent to `python setup.py build`). `poetry` is able to do this according to this [github issue](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/11). But to me it's not clear what to include into `pyproject.toml` that the C extension build is executed when building with `poetry build`?

Comment: According to the link in the question, add `build = 'build.py'` into the `[tool.poetry]` of `pyproject.toml`. Edit the question to show the contents of `build.py` and `pyproject.toml`.

Comment: The accepted answer is correct (+/- some modifications), so no need for a new one. However, I find examples useful, too, so started a repo for minimal C/C++ extensions built with poetry. Maybe it is useful in getting started :) https://github.com/FirefoxMetzger/mini-extension

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add `build.py` to the repo-root. E.g. if one has one header file directory and 2 source files:

```py
from distutils.command.build_ext import build_ext


ext_modules = [
    Extension("<module-path-imported-into-python>",
              include_dirs=["<header-file-directory>"],
              sources=["<source-file-0>", "<source-file-1>"],
             ),
]


class BuildFailed(Exception):
    pass


class ExtBuilder(build_ext):

    def run(self):
        try:
            build_ext.run(self)
        except (DistutilsPlatformError, FileNotFoundError):
            raise BuildFailed('File not found. Could not compile C extension.')

    def build_extension(self, ext):
        try:
            build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
        except (CCompilerError, DistutilsExecError, DistutilsPlatformError, ValueError):
            raise BuildFailed('Could not compile C extension.')


def build(setup_kwargs):
    """
    This function is mandatory in order to build the extensions.
    """
    setup_kwargs.update(
        {"ext_modules": ext_modules, "cmdclass": {"build_ext": ExtBuilder}}
    )
```

Add to `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.poetry]
build = "build.py"
```

To build the extension execute `poetry build`.

For an example refer to [this PR](https://github.com/welchbj/tt/pull/7/files).

Comment: I would like to note, that `build.py` is an unstable feature, that might be replaced by a more sophisticated build system for C-extensions: https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/2740

Comment: It's missing an import statement for the errors it supposedly should raise in case extension building fails 
`from distutils.errors import DistutilsPlatformError, CCompilerError, DistutilsExecError, DistutilsPlatformError`

Comment: Note that the `pyproject.toml` preferred syntax [changed several years ago](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/2740#issuecomment-1447608715).  Use this now: `[tool.poetry.build]`
`script = "build.py"`
`generate-setup-file = true`

Comment: Also PSA: [`distutils` is unmaintained and deprecated](https://peps.python.org/pep-0632/).  Import everything from `setuptools` now instead: `from setuptools.command import build_ext`